# mongod: symbol lookup error: mongod: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost6detail13once_epoch_cvE

Tags: mongodb, boost, debian

I am having trouble with my mongodb install :
when I run `sudo mongod`, I get `mongod: symbol lookup error: mongod: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost6detail13once_epoch_cvE`

```
uname -a
Linux xyz 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u2 i686 GNU/Linux

which mongod
/usr/bin/mongod

ldd /usr/bin/mongod
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb76e7000)
    libpcrecpp.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcrecpp.so.0 (0xb76b9000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0xb767b000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb758e000)
    libboost_system.so.1.49.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.49.0 (0xb758a000)
    libboost_thread.so.1.49.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.49.0 (0xb7565000)
    libboost_filesystem.so.1.49.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.49.0 (0xb7546000)
    libboost_program_options.so.1.49.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.49.0 (0xb74de000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libm.so.6 (0xb74b7000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb749a000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xb7481000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb731d000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb76e8000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/librt.so.1 (0xb7314000)
    libboost_system.so.1.57.0 => /lib/libboost_system.so.1.57.0 (0xb730f000)
```

I have reinstalled libboost and mongodb, but without success. any idea what's going on ?

BR/

Comment: How did you install MongoDB .. is this a packaged install, build from source, ..? Also what specific version of MongoDB? Note: admin questions like this are more appropriate for ServerFault.

Comment: ok moved to serverfault. https://serverfault.com/questions/680174/mongod-symbol-lookup-error-mongod-undefined-symbol-zn5boost6detail13once-ep